# What does it mean when we say some proposal is compliant with ERC4337?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, erc-4337, account-abstraction

https://twitter.com/johnrising_/status/1688949899419693068?s=46&t=LOD6kc1r6c1fbygDtT3Qvg

I was reading this twitter thread today . Then I read about EIP6900

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-6900
In the Abstract section , it is written that "This proposal is compliant with ERC-4337, ...".

What does it actually mean by being compliant to ERC4337 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no generic, or Ethereum specific, definition what it means "being compliant" outside those English words as they stand. You could translate it as "not in a conflict." However, like always, it is the best bet to ask the writer directly what he meant, as no one else is unlikely to know what was in his or her mind when this sentence was written.